# Java работа с массивом

Tags: java, android, массивы

если массив {true, true, true} result = true;
если массив {true, false, true} result = false;

```
    public static boolean mono(boolean[] data) {
    boolean result = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i] == data[0]) {
            result = true;
        } else {
            result = false;
        }
    }
        return result;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean[] a = {true,false,true};
    System.out.println(mono(a));
}
```

но в моем коде мравнивается последний элемент, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Из вашего кода и приведенных двух примеров неясно, чего вы хотите добиться. Если вам нужно проверить, равны ли друг другу все элементы массива, то правильный код -- в ответе woesss.

Answer (score 1):

По-моему тут требуется проверить не равенство элементов массива, а то, что все эти элементы - `true`. Например так:

```
public static boolean checkAllTrue(boolean... all) {
    boolean result = all != null && all.length > 0;
    for (int i = 0, j = result ? all.length : 0; i < j && (all[i] || (result = false)); i++);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Проверка на равенство всех элементов массива:

```
public static boolean mono(boolean[] data) {
    for (int i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i] != data[i - 1])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
     boolean[] a = {true,false,true};
     System.out.println(mono(a));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public boolean mono(boolean[] data) {
    boolean result = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i] != data[0]) {
            result = false;
            break;
        }
    }
        return result;
}
```